# Firefox negative margins and max-width greater than 100% issue

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I made a custom code for my Wordpress theme and I think that the margin and/or max width greater than 100% is causing Firefox to overflow and display horizontal scroll bar. Chrome renders the site fine (here's the site: http://bit.ly/1zXIxd5)

This is the part that causes the problem (I think)

```
@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
#content img {max-width: 157.5%; height: auto; margin-left: -28.5%;}
#okv {width: 157%; margin-left: -28.5%;}
#okp {width: 80%; margin: 5% 10% 5% 10%;}
.post .featured-image {margin-left: 28.5%;}
}
```

So if anyone knows the way to fix this, please let me know. Here's my full custom code if you need it.

```
.header {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
display: inline-block;
padding: 2.3% 2% 0% 2%;
text-align: center;
}

.post .post-content {font: 17px/1.6 sans-serif;}

@media all and (max-width: 799px) {
#content img {max-width: 100%; height: auto;}
#okv {width: 100%; margin-left: 0;}
#okp {width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;}
.post .post-content {font: 14px/1.6 sans-serif;}
.post .featured-image {margin-left: 0;}
}

@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
#content img {max-width: 157.5%; height: auto; margin-left: -28.5%;}
#okv {width: 157%; margin-left: -28.5%;}
#okp {width: 80%; margin: 5% 10% 5% 10%;}
.post .featured-image {margin-left: 28.5%;}
}

.nav a {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

h2 {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

.post .more-link:hover span {background: #e34234;}

p.wp-caption-text {text-align: center; font: 13px/1.6 sans-serif;}

p.mtx {font: 10px/1.6 sans-serif;}

.post .more-link span {background: #f6f6f6; border-radius: 3px; padding: 6px 23px;}
.entry-title {font-weight: bold;}
.twentytwenty-handle {top: -50%;}
.twentytwenty-horizontal .twentytwenty-handle:after, .twentytwenty-horizontal .twentytwenty-handle:before {width: 1px;}

.intro {display: inherit;}

.comments-wrap {
    width: 65%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 4% 0px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The margin-left on the image inside the anchor tag on line 178 needs to be set to 0.

You could do something like this:

```
.post .featured-image {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
}

.post .featured-image img {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: The top featured-image div was being shifted to the right by 28.5%, and then the image itself was pulled back using a negative 28.5% margin. This cause the div to be pushed off the edge of the page, while the image was position correctly. Don't forget mark my answer correct. Glad I could help!